# How to write a function that tests for time continuity?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, numpy

I have a large 3D numpy array of shape (100000, 24, 24). One of the column is full of integers which represents the hour of the day. Each band in this array must contain all 24 hours of the day in the correct order, but not all bands start at 0. This represents an array that didn't start at 00:00, which is fine.

Sometimes, the hour column skips hours or goes out of order. If this is the case, I need to remove this band completely.

For example, this is okay: `[20, 21, 22, 23, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`

This is not okay: `[0, 2, 3, 4, ...]`

I have figured this out, but it requires converting every column into pandas timeseries and uses a ton of memory. My solution also does not use vectorization. How do I do this efficiently and with numpy vectorization?

Minimum Reproducible Example using 5 hours instead of 24:

```py
import numpy as np
# Define the shape of the array, pretend we only have 1 column, 3 bands, and 5 rows.
shape = (3, 5, 1)
# Create the random 3D numpy array
random_array = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=shape)
# Assign these 2 bands as examples of ones that should stay 
random_array[0, :, :] = [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
random_array[1, :, :] = [[3], [4], [0], [1], [2]]
# Assign this one as one that should be removed
random_array[2, :, :] = [[1], [2], [4], [4], [0]]
```

Given this array, write a function that keeps the first two bands and removes the last.

Comment: need [mre] to answer

Comment: Which dimension of the array is the hours column? Can you give a small sample (e.g. (x,y,24) or (x,24,y) (where x and y are small) of your data?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need to create examples with specific times (integers between 0 and 23). Consider integers from 0 to 4 and generate examples, also providing the results of how they would be handled. You can sufficiently provide [mre]

Comment: I assume the following could appear: `[[20], [22], [21], [23], [0]]` Correct?

Comment: What I normally do is compute the `diff` along the time access and then filter for any diffs that are not equals to the sample frequency. Normally I use polars and a datetime column but it should work in your case as well - you're looking for diffs that aren't +1 or -23

Comment: yeet_man, please answer the questions raised in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, each value after the first should be the previous value + 1, mod 24. That can be accomplished pretty easily by slicing to isolate the column to be checked and applying a function such as the following:

```py
import numpy as np

def good_column(v):
    return np.all(arr_a[1:] == (arr_a[:-1] + 1) % 24)

good_column(np.array([0, 2, 3, 4]))    # False
good_column(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]))    # True
```

Comment: I went there, but was scared of corner cases potentially not being covered, but after careful thinking I think this is actually safe if apparent assumptions are met. Just suggest using `np.diff` instead of manually shifting slices...

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: all "hours" in your array are ints in [0-23].

TLDR:

```
test[(np.diff(test) % 24 == 1).all(axis=1)]
```

(possibly using different axis as per your needs)

For the details, consider this:

```
a = np.arange(24) # OK
b = (np.arange(24) + 5) % 24 # OK
c = (np.arange(24) + 5) % 24
c[10] = 0 # BAD
d = (np.arange(24) + 5) % 24
d[10:] = np.arange(14) # BAD
test = np.vstack((a,b,c,d))

diff = np.diff(test)

d1 = diff == 1
d_23 = diff == -23
```

`d1` tells you you are gaining 1 hour, `d_23` tells you you are loosing 23 hours

For a sequence to be ok you need both:

- either `d1` or `d3` is true at every step
- `d_23` is true no more than once

This can be coded as:

```
(d1 | d_23).all(axis=1) & (d_23.sum(axis=1) <= 1)
```

Output:

```
array([ True,  True, False, False])
```

You can then use this as mask:

```
test[(d1 | d_23).all(axis=1) & (d_23.sum(axis=1) <= 1)]
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

I also have the strong intuition that the second test (`(d_23.sum(axis=1) <= 1`) is not necessary since to have `d_23` true more than once, you'd also need to break the first condition. But I don't have the will to look at it carefully enough to mathematically prove it, I leave that to you... :)

Yes given assumption that hours are in [0,23] anyway, then this is redundant and can be collapsed to simple:

```
test[(d1 | d_23).all(axis=1)]
```

or even simpler 1-liner:

```
test[(np.diff(test) % 24 == 1).all(axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks but: the other columns of my arrays are not hours, they are other data that need to stay. So the diff line should be `np.diff(test, axis=1)`.  How do I only use the logic on one column? Let's assume the column in question is the 0th column?

Comment: Just use the axis you care about...

Comment: It is not indeed. Reason in ℤ/24ℤ: both d23 (aka -23) and d1 mean the same. Both are ≡ +1 [mod 24]. So, to have valid 1st test, means that, in ℤ/24ℤ, hour increments by +1 exactly. So, you cover all possible values of ℤ/24ℤ. And back in ℤ, the only way for that to be done with more that 1 d23, would be to have some values >23 or <0 in the list. Like '1 2 3 -20 -19 6 -17 ...'. When postulate is that the said column contains only number between 0 and 23

Comment: `MAX = 5 ; STEP = 1 ; out = random_array[(np.diff(random_array, axis=1)%MAX==STEP).all(axis=(1,2))]`

Answer (score 2):

With your example

```
l5=np.arange(5)
random_array[((random_array[:,:,0]-l5)%5 == random_array[:,:1,0]).all(axis=1)]
```

Or, for 24 hours

```
l24=np.arange(24)
random_array[((random_array[:,:,0]-l24)%24 == random_array[:,:1,0]).all(axis=1)]
```

Based on the fact that if a line [x₀, x₁, ×₂, ..., x₂₃] is ok then (xₖ-k)≡x₀ (mod 24), ∀k